# Java: How to reference a class var based on input #2

Tags: java, string, class, parameters, concatenation

I have a class with a mix of booleans and integers:

```
class Soup {
    boolean mItem1 = false
    boolean mItem2 = false
    int     mItem3 = 10
    boolean mItem4 = false
    int     mItem5 = 100 
{
```

I also have a method "void addIngredient(String itemName)" that I will pass a string value like "Item1" or "Item4".

```
void addIngredient(String itemName) {
    // I need help with the following line
    Soup.m(itemName) = true
}
```

How can I set the value of variable Soup.mItem1 for example, WITHOUT using an if statement or switch. For example I might add up to 25 or 50 "mItems" variables that may either be a boolean or integer value.

I basically want to take Soup.m and concatenate the string I pass (Item1 for example) to make the string "Soup.mItem1" and then set a value, such has "Soup.mItem1 = true" or "Soup.nItem3 = 1000".

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit more. What is `Soup.m(...)`? And what do you mean when you say - *25 or 50 "Items" that could be either a Int or Bool*?

Comment: Ok. You can't do this in Java. What you want is an `ArrayList` or a `HashMap` to store various values. Maintain an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and an `ArrayList<Boolean>`, and add values to it.

Comment: void addIngredient(String itemName) throws Exception {
    Soup.class.getDeclaredField("m" + itemName).setBoolean(this, false);
}

Comment: Can I do something like that? ^

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this other post that talk about how to turn a string that is passed in as a parameter or a variable and assign it a field. I think this will work, but I'd still do some more research: [Creating a variable name using a String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value) and [Get variable by name from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298823/get-variable-by-name-from-a-string)

This is what I came up with:

```
final Map<String, boolean> itemType = new HashMap<>();

void addIngredient(String itemName) {
itemName="m" + itemName;
itemType.put(itemName, true);
}
```

Think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html).

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main 
{
    private boolean mItem1;
    private int mItem2;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, 
               IllegalArgumentException, 
               IllegalAccessException 
    {
        final Main instance;

        instance = new Main();
        instance.addIngredient("Item1");
        instance.setIngredientAmount("Item2", 1000);

        System.out.println(instance.mItem1);
        System.out.println(instance.mItem2);
    }

    public void addIngredient(final String itemName) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, 
               IllegalArgumentException, 
               IllegalAccessException
    {
        final Class<Main> clazz;
        final Field       item;

        clazz = Main.class;
        item  = clazz.getDeclaredField("m" + itemName);
        item.set(this, true);
    }

    public void setIngredientAmount(final String itemName,
                                    final int    value)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, 
               IllegalArgumentException, 
               IllegalAccessException
    {
        final Class<Main> clazz;
        final Field       item;

        clazz = Main.class;
        item  = clazz.getDeclaredField("m" + itemName);
        item.set(this, value);
    }
}
```

I would not actually recommend this, but it should satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Reflection, but Reflection has a lot of caveats, including performance and a very tight coupling of code. So, I would recommend not using Reflection, but if you must, you can do it like this.

**OriginalClass**

```
public class OriginalClass {
    public int var1;
    public String var2;
    public boolean var3;
}
```

**Main**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        OriginalClass orig = new OriginalClass();
        orig.var1 = 1;
        orig.var2 = "Hello";
        orig.var3 = true;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            Field origVar = OriginalClass.class.getDeclaredField("var" + i);
            System.out.println(origVar.get(orig));
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `getFields` and then loop over all the fields.

```
for(Field origVar : orig.getFields())
    System.out.println(origVar.get(orig));
```

Similar to the `get()` method, there is the `set()` method on `Field`. The signature is

```
void set(Object obj, Object value);
```

**Note** : Normally, due to encapsulation, your member variables will be hidden, so you must access them through their getters and setters, something like this.

```
Method m = OriginalClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("getVar1", null);
System.out.println(m.invoke(orig));
m = OriginalClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("setVar1", Integer.TYPE);
m.invoke(orig, 3);
System.out.println(orig.var1); //Will print 3
```