# How can you multiply a string with an integer in Java?

Tags: java

I was just writing code for project that's due for class but I'm having a problem because I need to multiply my string with a number. Here's parts of my code

```
int shoes=50;
int shirts=30;
int shorts=75;
int caps=15;
int jackets=100;
```

Those above are the products and how much they cost in dollars:

```
    System.out.print("Enter the product: ");
String product=keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the quantity of the product");
int quantity=keyboard.nextInt();    
System.out.print("cost= +product+*+quantity+");
int cost= product*quantity;
```

This is the error I'm having:
The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) string, int

Any suggestions?

Comment: How on earth is `cost = product * quantity` a sensible equation? What are you reading into `product`? Is it `cost/product`? If yes, shouldn't that be declared as an `int` too?

Comment: @RohitJain It's not if you're buying something

Comment: Your print should be `System.out.print("cost= " + product*quantity);`

Comment: What do you mean with multiply a string by an integer. Can you give more explanation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that you've stored cost/product in variables. In that case, you certainly need a `Map`, else you can't get the product cost from string

Comment: Let's say I want 3 caps. The string would be caps and the quanitity would be 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get variable by name from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298823/get-variable-by-name-from-a-string)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to map each product with its cost.

```
Map<String, Integer> productMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
productMap.put("shoes",50);
...
```

And then just do:

```
int cost= productMap.get(product)*quantity;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to look up a price given a product name. One way is using a `Map`:

```
Map<String,Integer> productPrices = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

This creates a container that will hold `Integer` values that can be looked up using a `String`.

Then add your products to it:

```
productPrices.put("shoes", 50);
productPrices.put("shirts", 30);
```

and so on. Then to calculate your cost:

```
Integer cost = productPrices.get(product) * quantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to and integer first:

```
int stringAsInt = 0;
try{
  stringAsInt  = Integer.parseInt(yourStringHere);
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
  //Log error here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `Map` in order to take the product type as an input and retrieve an integer output that is the cost of the type of product.

```
Map<String, Integer> products = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
products.put("shoes", 50);
```

and retrieve the value using

```
products.get("shoes");
```

You can find more on HashMaps [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).