# PHP's variable variables analog in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

In PHP we can do the following with the help of [Variable variables in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$privateVar = 'Hello!';
$publicVar = 'privateVar';
echo $$publicVar; // Hello!
```

Suppose we have the following chunk of Java code:

```
request.setAttribute("privateVar", "Hello!");
request.setAttribute("publicVar", "privateVar");
```

I've tried the following but an error occurs.

```
${${publicVar}}
```

Does anyone know how we can get value of `privateVar` via using only `publicVar` in JSP (JSTL)?

**UPDATE 1**:

I have a custom tag which allows to print a message if an object `foo` doesn't have a field `bar`.
I know I must catch exceptions in the case but I don't want to handle ones in JSP. I want to do it only in CustomTag file.

```
<%-- JSP file --%>
<ctf:tagName varName="foo.bar" />

<%-- CustomTag file --%>
<%@ attribute name="varName" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"%>
<c:catch var="exception">
    <c:set var="valX" value="${${varName}}" scope="page"/>
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${exception != null}">Can't find getter for the VAR in the OBJ.</c:if>
```

**UPDATE 2**:

**JB Nizet** gave me the answer and the following works well! :)

```
<c:set var="privateVar" value="Hello!" />
<c:set var="publicVar" value="privateVar" />
${pageScope[pageScope.publicVar]}
```

Comment: Perhaps `${requestScope[publicVar]}` will do what you need?

Comment: @wasabi nope, that will print `privateVar` since that's the value of `publicVar` attribute.

Comment: updated with real situation

Comment: ${requestScope[requestScope[publicVar]]}

Comment: @JB Nizet thank you!) UPDATE 2.

Answer (score 0):

The basics:

That's not JSTL but [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el.htm). And you should only use a single `${}` evaluator. The code would be:

```
${publicVar}
```

More info:

- [StackOverflow Expression Language wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

To your problem:

Expression Language doesn't allow that. You cannot have *private* attributes in any scope (page, request, session, application), so you can at most set the attribute twice with different names but the same value. But as you may note, this is useless.

Comment: i think op wants to resolve `Hello!` using `publicVar` -> `privateVar`

Comment: We can't use `publicVar`. We can use only `publicVar` which holds the name of `publicVar` as string.

Comment: @oshilan you have a bad design. As noted here, it is futile. Why do you have to use such approach? It would be better if you add more details to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly do this in the same way that you can in PHP. Instead you could change the attribute to use the value of the `privateVar` instead of the name, like this:

```
String privateVar = "Hello!";
request.setAttribute("privateVar", privateVar);
request.setAttribute("publicVar", privateVar);
```

This gives you access to the value under both names, which I think is the closest you'd get. No need to even put the attribute `privateVar` in the request if you are ultimately going to use `publicVar` on the JSP.

Ultimately you may want to rethink the design here as it doesn't really work in Java.

Comment: Here's another question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298823/get-variable-by-name-from-a-string