# Trying to use the String of a name to call an array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to do this?
I'm trying to call an array using a String of it's name

```
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int [] temp=new int [1];
    temp[0]=1;
      String a="temp";

      System.out.println(a[0]);
     }
```

Comment: This is not possible in Java because Java is not a dynamic language.  This is what `Map<>` data structures are for.  This is also an example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  If you would explain what you _really_ want to accomplish we might be able to help, but with such a bare bones example all we can say is "You can't do that in Java".  I suggest you flesh out the question with a meaningful example, or risk attracting downvotes.

Comment: Similarly: [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get variable by name from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298823/get-variable-by-name-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

NO this is not possible as the variable names cannot be declared dynamically in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a HashMap it is similar to what your looking for.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> test = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    test.put("Temp", 1);
    test.put("Temp2", 2);

    System.out.println(test.get("Temp")); // returns one

    HashMap<Integer, String> test2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    test2.put(1, "Temp");
    test2.put(2, "Temp2");

    System.out.println(test2.get(1)); // returns one
}
```

This is an interesting question if you want to know the differences between Map vs HashMap.

[What is the difference between the HashMap and Map objects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects)