# Java: how to access a class by a name saved in a variable?

Tags: java, string, class

I have something like this:

```
String currentRoom = "NameOfRoom";
static room NameOfRoom = new room();
```

And I want to activate a function that is inside the room by accessing it through the variable `currentRoom`.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,
Ethan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get variable by name from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298823/get-variable-by-name-from-a-string)

Comment: See if you can use a ``Map`` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a variable name using a String value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value)

Comment: This is most certainly *not* what you want to do. There are better ways to do this. Reflection *can* do this, but most of the times, you don't.

Comment: Also note that there is a widely accepted convention in java that class names should start with an upper-case letter, while variable names should start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I got you.

But you can use [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to maintain mapping between strings and object instances.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("NameOfRoom", new Room());
```

Now retrieve from map

```
map.get("NameOfRoom")
```