# Building String name using concatenation with a for loop

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I want to create a run time String name in Java.
I tried something like using in JavaScript, but it is printing value like **Status_Name_0** instead **Open** assigned to the String **Status_Name_0**

```
 public static void GetPaymentStatusList(){
        int i=0;
        String Status_Name_0="Open";
        String Status_ID_0="0";
        String Status_Name_1="Approved";
        String Status_ID_1="1";
        String Status_Name_2="Denied";
        String Status_ID_2="2";
        for(i=0; i<3; i++){
            Vars.PaymentStatusName_List.add("Status_Name_"+i);
            Vars.PaymentStatusId_List.add("Status_ID_"+i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use String builder or String buffer for this purpose

Comment: Post your full code..where you are printing values..

Comment: thanxx yaar i will try @AbdulKawee

Comment: What you want?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get variable by name from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298823/get-variable-by-name-from-a-string)

Comment: @Meenal already i have posted full code for the function

Comment: What do you mean you tried this is JavaScript?

Comment: @JDC not the same please look at the question correctly, have to use String builder here as Abdul said

Comment: Han Try kro agar na howa to i will help you @Error404 :)

Comment: Sure acha thanks a lot @AbdulKawee

Comment: As far as I can read it, you want to access a variables value by using the name of the variable as a `String`, so from my point of view this should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually concatenating the string "Status_name_" with "0" which would result in "Status_name_0", a string, not a variable like Status_name_0. As far as I understand, you want the values of String_name_i (i= 0, 1, 2,....). To get that working, use String array.

```
String[] string_names = { "Open", "Approved", "Denied" };

int[] string_id = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

:You may not need a string_id array, as you can use the values of i in the for loop.

And add them in the list like:

```
Vars.PaymentStatusName_List.add(string_name[i]);
```

Comment: This is what i want thaxx yaar

Answer (score 1):

> but it is printing value like Status_Name_0 instead Open

Because that's what you added to the list...

> ```
>  add("Status_Name_"+i);
> ```

The way to get what you want would be a `Map<String, String>`

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Status_Name_0", "Open");
// ...

for (int i=0;i<map.size();i++) {
    String open = map.get("Status_Name_"+i);
}
```

---

How about you make some class instead, though?

```
public class PaymentStatus {

    int id;
    String name;

    public PaymentStatus(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id; 
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[id: %d, name: %s]",
            getClass().getSimpleName(), id, name);
    }
}
```

And a `List<PaymentStatus>` would be preferred over appending integers to any variables.

```
 public static List<PaymentStatus> getPaymentStatusList() {
    List<PaymentStatus> list = new ArrayList<>();

    paymentStatusList.add(new PaymentStatus(0, "Open"));
    paymentStatusList.add(new PaymentStatus(1, "Approved"));
    paymentStatusList.add(new PaymentStatus(2, "Denied"));

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
param.append("shopid"
        + "=" + shopDetails.getShopId() + "&" + "username" + "=" + userDetail.getUserName() + "&" + "userid" + "=" + userDetail.getUserId() + "&");
for (int i = 0; i < brandList.size(); i++) {
    param.append("brandId" + "[" + i + "]" + "=" + brandList.get(i).getBrandId()
            + "&" + "shortqua" + "[" + i + "]" + "=" + shortageStockList.get(i) + "&");
}
param.append("lattude" + "=" + String.valueOf(latitude) + "&" + "longitude" + "=" + String.valueOf(longitude));
```

Comment: Explain your answers rather than dump unrelated, hard to read code, please.

Comment: I am asking him to post your string which is he wants that not mean hard to read code

Comment: Ok , for that actually I don't know that