# Adding string to ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

We can add a string to an `ArrayList<String[]>` as:

```
ArrayList<String[]> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
array1.add(new String[]{"word"});
```

But how can we add a string to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>` directly without creating array1. Something like:

```
array2.add(new ArrayList<>(new String[]{"hello"}));
```

Comment: Why do you mix array with `List`s? Why not just one or the other (preferably: why not just `List`s)?

Comment: I am working with nlp. I am using an array to store word-tag combinations in an array (arraylist<string[]>). But now, i have to process that array once again and add combinations of (word-tag),(word-tag)-tag . To put it simply, i want to make an arraylist, with arraylists as elements, but the last element, a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
array2.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<String[]>asList(new String[]{"hello"})));
```

There is no `ArrayList(ArrayOfElements)` constructor, but we can use `ArrayList(CollectionOfElementsToCopy)` constructor. With that all we need to do is wrap elements into some collection. For that we can use `Arrays.asList(elements)`.

Problem with `Arrays.asList` is that it uses `T...` varargs which by default represents array of elements. If we want to tell that array *is* element we can do it by explicitly specifying `<String[]>` as method generic type.

Comment: I wouln't write such a code because it isn't really readable if the count of elements in the array raise, but for this problem it is a very elegant solution... +1

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if there is a way we can use a string to represent the arraylist name. For example, ArrayList<ArrayList> newArray = new ArrayList<>(); and in another array, ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<>(); now lets say stringArray has two strings-> string1,string2. Is it possible to somehow associate string1 to newArray and access its elements through string1?

Comment: @Dante For associating one thing with another we use maps. So you are probably looking for a `Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>>`.

Comment: @Dante Possibly related: [Get variable by name from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13298823)

Comment: Thank you. This eased it out a lot :)